# Django Projekt Management

Tags: django, model, project

im currently facing the problem that i want to call a view from another app (accounts app which holds the user model) within my main app (a blog app).

this is the error i get:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for User
```

urls.py

```
...
from quickblog import views as core_views
from accounts import views as views_accounts

...
url(r'^myaccount/$', views_accounts.view_profile, name='myaccount'),
```

views.py (accounts app):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse

from accounts.forms import (
    RegistrationForm,
    EditProfileForm
)

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:home'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'reg_form.html', args)


def view_profile(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
    args = {'user': user}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', args)


def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', args)


def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:change_password'))
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'change_password.html', args)
```

profile.html:

```
{% extends 'quickblog/base.html' %}


{% block head %}
<title>Profile</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <p>Username: {{ user }}</p>
    <p>Bio: {{ user.bio }}</p>
    <p>Avatar: {{ user.avatar }}</p>
    {% if user.avatar.image %}
    <img src="{{ user.avatar.image.url }}" width="250">
    {% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is my first django app, is there maybe anything i need to know about linking two apps within one project?

thanks

Comment: It seems, the error are in profile.html template. Can I see that template?

Comment: @ Mohammad Ali. Just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the error at forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    user = forms.CharField(required=True)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
        'username', < has to be user
        'password1',
        'password2',
    )
```

anyways, thanks everybody :)